# Plugin screenshots not showing in the repository

Tags: plugin-development, troubleshooting, plugin-repository

I'm having major trouble getting the screenshots to show in my plugin.

I have validated the readme file and placed the screenshots in both the `/trunk` and `/tags/1.0` directories (1.0 is stable). I have looked at many search results and quite a few existing plugins to see what I'm doing different but I'm failing to see what, if anything, I am doing wrong.

The output of running [pngcheck](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html) is

```
$ pngcheck trunk/*.png
OK: trunk/screenshot-1.png (1418x761, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced, 98.4%).
OK: trunk/screenshot-2.png (699x373, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced, 77.6%).
OK: trunk/screenshot-3.png (370x701, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced, 70.1%).
OK: trunk/screenshot-4.png (935x331, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced, 93.8%).

No errors were detected in 4 of the 4 files tested.
```

The plugin repo is at http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/tel-link-obfuscate/
The screenshots section of the WP plugin page just displays the description of the plugin
Obviously any help is appreciated and until then I'll just have to live without screenshots on my plugin page.

Comment: Yes, strange... Shouldn't be an issue, but move all screenshots to the root folder `/assets/`, they don't need to be inside `trunk` or `tags` and this reduces the plugin download size. Check the following articles regarding [*readme*](http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/tag/readme/) and [*screenshots*](http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/tag/screenshots/).

Comment: Hi Brasofilo,Yes, that has worked a treat, after searching through forum post after forum post last night, that worked. As much as I had searched before I had not come across the screenshots page.

Thank you again for your help :-)

Comment: I think it was a bug, but will document the new use of the `/assets/` folder as an Answer.

Answer (score 4):

If it's the first time you are using the assets folder, do not forget to:

**svn add assets/***

and commit the updates. ;-)

I was wondering why my banner image / screenshots were not showing and realized I didn't even add them to SVN!

HTH!

Answer (score 3):

Given that the `readme.txt` was ok and there was no apparent problem with the image files, I'm inclined to think it was a bug in the system, and in such cases it should be reported to `plugins@wordpress.org`.

Anyway, [since december 2012](http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/09/13/last-december-we-added-header-images-to-the/), the root folder `/assets`<sup>[1]</sup> is being used to store the screenshots files as well as the [header images](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/21/been-giving-a-lot-of-thought-to-how/) (or banner files).

The main reason is that the screenshots are rarely used by plugins itself and simply inflate the zip file size.

Important notes from the article that announces the change: <sup>*my emphasis*</sup>

> - **Screenshot naming conventions have not changed**, nor have the readme.txt requirements for their captioning. The naming and behavior
>     is exactly the same, the file can just go into a new place.
> - **The old way still works too**. If you have your screenshots in the plugin’s “stable” directory, then it will find them there just
>     fine.
> - Screenshots in **the assets directory take precedence** over screenshots in the plugin’s directory. If you have both, then the
>     assets directory wins. Of course, there’s really no reason to have
>     both, this is just for backwards compatibility.

<sup>[1] optional directory that sits alongside the /tags and /trunk directories</sup>

Comment: Is everyone using mardown this way then:
![Plugin Name](/wp-widgets/assets/widget.jpg) ?